# How to Configure HockeyApp in Swift 3 ios

Tags: ios, xcode, hockeyapp

I have configured Hockey App SDK with iOS. But the problem is nothing showing on my Hockey App server.
`

```
    BITHockeyManager.shared().configure(withIdentifier: "HOCKEYID")    
    BITHockeyManager.shared().crashManager.crashManagerStatus = BITCrashManagerStatus.autoSend
    BITHockeyManager.shared().logLevel = .debug
    BITHockeyManager.shared().start()
    print("BITHockeyManager version \(BITHockeyManager.shared().version()) build \(BITHockeyManager.shared().build())")

    // Test Crash
    BITHockeyManager.shared().crashManager.generateTestCrash()`
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you are properly receiving crash data make sure the following things are true:

1. The `identifier:` in your code matches the `App ID` on the HockeyApp website.
2. You are crashing the app without a debugger i.e. the IDE being attached. So basically, first install the app on the device, then disconnect the cable from the device, run and crash the app.
3. You reopened the app after it crashed as crash reports are only sent on the next app start.

Comment: Also make sure not to crash right after launch, because the SDK won't have time to send out the crash then as the app crashes right away.

Answer (score -2):

According to your coding, if you have used write "HOCKEYID" and on Hockey dashboard correct bundle Id. Then no need to worry.

It will take some time to update first time on Dashboard.

Around of it will take at maximum 24 hours.